# How do I wrap Func<dynamic, MyClass> property

Tags: c#, lambda, func

This is simplified setup - I have API (I have n o control on the API), which exposes a Func property like this:

```
public Func<dynamic, MyClass> FuncProperty { get; set; }
```

Usually it's used like this:

```
api.FuncProperty = s =>
   {
      do1();
      do2();
      return new MyClass(); //simplified
   }
```

Similar code is used all over the place (of course the content in {} is different), and I want to add common functionality to all these, I'd like to create a "wrapper" method, which I can use like this:

```
api.FuncProperty = MyWrapperMethod( 
   s =>
   {
      do1();
      do2();
      return new MyClass();
   });
```

I know I can edit all these calls to look like:

```
api.FuncProperty = s =>
  {
     DoMyCommonFunctionality();
     //... as before
  }
```

But if my common functionality is something like:

```
using(var disposable = SetSomeState())
{
   //the stuff which previously was in the lambda
}
```

then, using the latter approach is kind of ugly.

That's why even if it's only for learning purposes, how should my wrapper's method signature look like? And how should I use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you right, it should also return a `Func<dynamic, MyClass>`, like this:

```
public static Func<dynamic, MyClass> MyWrapperMethod(Func<dynamic, MyClass> func)
{
    // Validation if you want
    return d =>
    {
        using(var disposable = SetSomeState())
        {
            return func(d);
        }
    };
}
```

That's an example with the `using` statment you wanted.

Note that calling `MyWrapperMethod` does *not* call the delegate you pass into it. Instead, it returns a delegate which, when called, will call the delegate you passed. This sort of deferred execution can be confusing, but I believe it's what you want here.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
public Func<dynamic, MyClass> MyWrapperMethod(Func<dynamic, MyClass> func)
{
    if (func == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("func");

    return s => {
        DoMyCommonFunctionality();

        // Execute original function
        return func(s);
    };
}
```

Note that it looks like you're using delegate properties to simulate methods.  This smells like a very bad architecture to me.

Comment: Thanks, that what I need. Small explanation: it's not smell - I used property to simplify. Actually, I'm using Nancy (https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Documentation), and this is not a property but an indexer with the defined routes, and the actions for each of them. I wanted to wrap NDC logging around each of the calls.

Comment: I see, so the example was somewhat misleading.

Comment: It sums up what I need, I didn't want to go deep and explain. And you answered exactly what I need :). Thanks again. Btw, I would not mind someone editing the question to the way it should be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing this:

**Suggestion One**

Creating a different signature for your delegate:

```
 public Func<HelperObject<dynamic>, MyClass> FuncProperty { get; set; }
```

Then your method changes like so:

```
 api.FuncProperty = h =>
    {
        //h.Model is the dynamic
        //h.CommonHelperFunction()
        return new MyClass();
    };
```

And then invoke like so:

```
 api.FuncProperty(new HelperObject(someDynamic));
```

**Suggestion Two**

Create an extension method on dynamic to give you the data you need.

```
public static MyHelperClass CreateHelper(this object obj)
{
     return new MyHelperClass();
}
```

And you could then use it like so:

```
api.FuncProperty = s =>
  {
      var helper = (s as object).CreateHelper();

      return new MyClass();
  };
```

**Suggestion Three**

Remove the delegate as a property from your object and change it to a method abstraction:

```
 public MyClass ExecuteFunc(Func<dynamic, MyClass> selector)
 {
      Func<MyClass> helper = () =>
         {
             DoCommonFunctionality();
             return selector(x.Model);
         };

      return helper();
 }
```

Then you would call like so:

```
 api.ExecuteFunc(x => 
    {
        return new MyClass();
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, but I do not have control on the API.